# Get youtube video Id from shared video Url

Tags: android

I'm using following code for getting video id from Url.This function returns Id for https://www.youtube.com/shared?ci=4xtFG3fPrk8 Url, But youtube plays shows me error that the 'video is unavailable'

```
 public static String extractYTId(String ytUrl) {
    String vId = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            "(?<=shared\\?ci=|watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|watch\\?v%3D|\u200C\u200B%2Fvideos%2F|embed%2\u200C\u200BF|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2\u200C\u200BF)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ytUrl);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        vId = matcher.group();
        Log.e(TAG, "video id found : " + vId);

    }
    return vId;
}
```

thanks

Comment: please show the url you are using for setting the video

Comment: u should use the same url cannot use the id of shared youtube link

Comment: that id will match only shared link not for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube ID of shared and real link are unique id representing the video

Hence you will need to distuinguish each other checking if it is shared or real by using a condition and use the link for shared :

"https://www.youtube.com/shared?ci="+(youtubeID)

and other using watch:

"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + (youtubeID)